# What is meaning of for in "for Christmas"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

What do you buy **for** Christmas？ We are going to buy a turkey **for** Christmas?

What is the meaning of for？Something for Christmas means something to celebrate Christmas?

Comment: You should look up "for" in a dictionary, and see if one (or more) of  the definitions there would fit your quotation.

Comment: I tried. But I could not understand the explaination of the dictionaries.

Comment: It can have several senses. _I'm going there for Christmas_ - I'm spending Christmas there. _Buy a turkey for Christmas_ - to cook for our Christmas dinner. _Buy her a necklace for Christmas_ - as her Christmas present.

Answer (score 5):

Three of the definitions found in [MACMILLAN](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/for):
**for**
"used for stating the purpose of an object or action"
"relating to or concerning someone or something"

(14) "in order to celebrate a holiday or special occasion":

- *John gave me a tie for Christmas, as usual.*
- *We haven’t decided what to do for her birthday.*

Comment: "I'll be back home for Christmas" certainly fits with the definition (14), using a purpose clause ('in order to ...'). "John gave me a tie for Christmas" is better paraphrased using "... as a Christmas present". And "We haven’t decided what to do for her birthday" would drop the 'in order'; "We haven’t decided where to go for her birthday" is a comparable sentence showing that there is a choice available.

Comment: Thank you very much. It clarifies the meanings of for.